# Object in a loop, it does not increment?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

```
for (let x= 0; x < nb; x++){
       tab = datas.splice(0,11);
 
       let arr ={
               x : {
               'nom' : tab[0],
               'prenom' : tab[10],
               'age' : tab[1]
       }
};
```

Here is the context,
a for loop that loops several times,
and an 'arr' object and my problem is that the x does not increment, it is called x during a console.log when the data is the right one ..
Do you know how to make the x equal to the x in the for loop? 0, 1, 2 ..

Comment: what is `datas` and what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi, Please add some more basic information. But by looking at the code I think you want something like, first define an array`let arr = [];` and then push objects in that array. `arr.push({'nom' : tab[0],'prenom' : tab[10],'age' : tab[1]})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (let x= 0; x < nb; x++){
       tab = datas.splice(0,11);
 
       let arr ={
               [x] : {
               'nom' : tab[0],
               'prenom' : tab[10],
               'age' : tab[1]
       }
};
```

Just wrap the `x` in a square bracket and it should work. In javascript when you use `x` as a key it will set alphabet x as the key but when you wrap it with square brackets then it will take the value of x as the key.